# Table or CSS to align these survey form elements?

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm building a basic survey creation system, and I want it to look more or less like this. [image: sample survey image] I'm tempted to use a table to align the questions and answer choices horizontally and vertically, but I know tables are for tabular data. Does this qualify as tabular data?

If CSS is preferable, can you give me a rough outline of how to achieve it (just on the alignment, not the alternate shading)? Would I need a series of classes, each with an increasingly wider left margin?

I snipped the image from SurveyMonkey, and I'd follow their example, except they use tables.

I searched for similar questions, but they all concerned *vertical* alignment, not horizontal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this qualifies as tabular data: All values in a row belong "together" as well all entries in a column have the same meaning.

In general tables should not be misued for layouts, but in this case you're really working with tabular data. Especially for disabled people, e.g. people using screen readers, misusing tables cause confusion, but in this case it's correct to use them.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a table moment. Table like gifs have their times and places. If you do decided to go the div route, one master div holds 4 rows that are absolute/fixed and then there is a div for each radio button. Div tags in a table thats the ticket!

Comment: Thank you. I accepted Mr Tux's answer not because yours was wrong, which it's not, but because he explained _why_ using a table was ok here. Welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way! :)